# Discord.js send message then wait until you reply

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I've been trying to code a Discord bot and I can't figure out how to make it wait until you say Y or N. Right now, I'm trying to code the ban command and it works pretty well until it asks you to say Y or N. Then once it asks that and you answer, nothing happens.

Here's the code:

```js
module.exports = {
    name: 'ban',
    description: 'This bans a member!',
    execute (message, args){
        var member = message.mentions.users.first();
        if(member){
            var memberTarget = message.guild.members.cache.get(member.id);
            message.channel.send(`Are you sure you want to ban ${member}? (Y or N)`);
            var messagethingy = message.first()
            var askingBan = ('1')
            do { if (messagethingy.content.toLowerCase === 'y' || messagethingy.content.toLowerCase === 'yes' || messagethingy.content.toLowerCase === 'n' || messagethingy.content.toLowerCase === 'no'); {
                
                if (messagethingy.content.toLowerCase === 'no' || messagethingy.content.toLowerCase === 'n') {
                    message.channel.send('The Action has been cancelled')
                    var askingBan = ('0')
                    return
                } else if (messagethingy.content.toLowerCase === 'y' || messagethingy.content.toLowerCase === 'yes') {
                    message.channel.send(`You have banned ${member}!`)
                    memberTarget.ban();
                    var askingBan = ('0')
                }}                
            }
            while (askingBan = '1');

        } else {
            message.channel.send("You couldn't ban that member!");
        }
    }
}
```

FYI these commands are in a different thingy. The main commands are in `main.js` and the command that senses when you say `ban` works perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of a do-while loop, you can use a message collector. You can send a confirmation message and in the same channel set up a collector using [`createMessageCollector`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=createMessageCollector).

For its filter, you can check if the incoming message is coming from the same user who want to ban the member, and check if the message content is one of the accepted answers (y, yes, n, no). You can convert the message to lowercase to make it case insensitive.

You can also add some options, like the maximum number of accepted answers, and the maximum time the collector is collecting messages. I set it to one minute, and after a minute it sends a message letting the original poster know that the action is cancelled.

```js
module.exports = {
  name: 'ban',
  description: 'This bans a member!',
  async execute(message, args) {
    const member = message.mentions.members.first();

    if (!member) {
      return message.channel.send('You need to mention a member you want to ban!');
    }

    // TODO: check if message.author can ban users

    const confirmation = await message.channel.send(`Are you sure you want to ban ${member}? (Y or N)`);
    const answers = ['y', 'yes', 'n', 'no'];
    const filter = (m) =>
      answers.includes(m.content.toLowerCase()) &&
      m.author.id === message.author.id;

    const collector = confirmation.channel.createMessageCollector(filter, {
      max: 1,
      time: 60000,
    });

    collector.on('collect', async (m) => {
      if (
        m.content.toLowerCase() === answers[2] ||
        m.content.toLowerCase() === answers[3]
      ) {
        return message.channel.send(
          `The action has been cancelled, ${member} is not banned.`
        );
      }

      try {
        await member.ban();
        return message.channel.send(`You have banned ${member}!`);
      } catch (error) {
        return message.channel.send(`Oops, error: ${error}`);
      }
    });

    collector.on('end', (collected, reason) => {
      if (reason === 'time') {
        message.channel.send(
          `${message.author}, it's been a minute without confirmation. The action has been cancelled, ${member} is not banned.`
        );
      }
    });
  },
};
```

[image]